# Images Not shown by AWS server with localhost default request

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, zend-framework2, aws-sdk

I have AWS server when i Tried with full path it show image properly but when i used to Default localhost address and continue with remain address it not showing image

http://54.179.169.78/restaurant/public/sitemedia/user/images/YsskKGF1H1jgI6YBM2wXIpPHN1SDg51438692997155c0b685891541438692997.png 
this with show image

but when i use 
http://54.179.169.78/sitemedia/user/images/YsskKGF1H1jgI6YBM2wXIpPHN1SDg51438692997155c0b685891541438692997.png

it not showing result. What should i Do ?

Comment: Please provide more details. What is your intended setup? Include your code.

Comment: check mentioned png file is there in the location

Answer (score -1):

please check your folder access level .. 
i have checked and tried to access the link.
http://54.179.169.78/sitemedia/user/images/YsskKGF1H1jgI6YBM2wXIpPHN1SDg51438692997155c0b685891541438692997.png

seems like you have either not created the mentioned directory .. 
or there is a problem of access level ...

Comment: I want to access it without Port

Comment: if i can see the panel where you have uploaded your image and your script ?